# How viable is QML for a user interface over a 3D game?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qml

As an option for rendering UI over a game I am currently developing I was thinking about how viable QML (Qt5) would be. Given that you are limited to only drawing when Qt *gives you the signal*, how viable would writing a game such as; a first person shooter of the quality of say... ArmA 3 (graphically wise, not taking into account content creation or budget); be in Qt/QML on a desktop platform if you used QML for **only** a 2D interface over top of the game (think menus and HUDs)?

To be more specific, what sort of performance loss would you get by rendering a high-fidelity FPS game [like this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) then rendering an interface over it using QML?

Comment: I don't think anyone can comment on performance loss without knowing more about your target platforms. On a desktop PC performance loss will almost certainly be nominal because Qt makes a good effort not to generate excessive draw calls (which are historically the bottleneck when using a generic UI system).

Comment: @DanO in a game engine, not getting **enough** draw-calls could be a bottleneck because you get a pile-up of events that need to be done all at once rather than as they happen.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be closed. It is a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", isn't too vague (only depends on X11, Win32, SurfaceFlinger and Cocoa) and does not fit in to [the "off-topic" section of the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didn't nominate it for closure - but there's no way I can answer your question. If games can ship using Scaleform they can certainly ship using Qt5, the question becomes unanswerable because you provide no details of scale, platforms, budget, or featureset...

Comment: @DanO good point, but I don't think you could do something like scaleform with QML **over** OpenGL. I'll edit my question to be more specific.